# Supress abort messages in python fabric with non zero exit status

Tags: python, python-2.7, fabric, traceback

My program runs a command on remote host and some secret parameters are passed as command line to fabric run function. But if the command returns a non zero status, it prints the complete command on the stderr.

I tried the below code

```
class FabricException(Exception):
    def __init__(self, message):
        self.message = message
        print self.message

env.abort_exception = FabricException

try:
    execute(fabric_run, intepreter=intepreter, script_name=script_name, command_line=command_line, hosts=hosts, sudo=sudo, warn_only=warn_only)
except FabricException("Something"):
    sys.exit(1)
```

But at any point of time, if the programs returns a non zero exit status, i get the traceback printed on the console which i want to avoid. Is there anyway that i can achieve this in fabric? I want this to work when warn_only is True as well as warn_only is False

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress the messages using fabric context_managers when warn_only = True.  With warn_only = False it seems to display the errors even when using context_managers to hide everything.  The quiet() context_manager is an alias to settings(hide('everything'), warn_only=True). See the example below:

```
>>> from fabric.api import run, execute
>>> from fabric.context_managers import quiet
>>> def task_a():
...  return run('sdfsdgfsd')
...
>>> with quiet():
...  a = execute(task_a,hosts=['testhost'])
...
>>> a
{'testhost': '/bin/bash: sdfsdgfsd: command not found'}
```

With the default warn_only = False:

```
>>> from fabric.context_managers import hide
>>> def task_a():
...  return run('sdfsdgfsd')
...
>>> with hide('everything'):
...  a = execute(task_a,hosts=['testhost'])
...

Fatal error: run() received nonzero return code 127 while executing!

Requested: sdfsdgfsd
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "sdfsdgfsd"

============================================================================================= Standard output =============================================================================================

/bin/bash: sdfsdgfsd: command not found

============================================================================================================================================================================================================

Aborting.
run() received nonzero return code 127 while executing!

Requested: sdfsdgfsd
Executed: /bin/bash -l -c "sdfsdgfsd"

============================================================================================= Standard output =============================================================================================

/bin/bash: sdfsdgfsd: command not found

===========================================================================================================================================================================================================
```

Comment: When `warn_only = False` , I can still see the errors printed to stderr which i want avoid. In case i passed some secrets/passwords as commandline, it gets displayed in the console which is not safe.